Share Extension not appearing in the list of apps with React Native App
I have the issue that my share extension does not show op on the share screen. I tried changing development target like written in this post Share Extension not appearing in the list of apps on capable of Sharing Photo on iPhone but no success. This is extension deployment target:

And this is my Main Target:

This is how my Info.plist for the extension looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ShareViewController</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Any ideas what the problem could be?
